# Raw data on sexual behavior

Tags: data-request, medical, lgbt

I am a college students doing a small research project on sexual behavior and was wondering if there was any raw data on sexual behavior that I would be able to access. It would really help me out. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: what is ISO besides https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Organization_for_Standardization?

Comment: industry standard(s) of sexual behavior? lol...i too, am very curious what ISO means in this context.

Comment: It means "In Search Of."

Comment: I edited out ISO in the title

Comment: Maybe look in the references section of the book "Dataclysm", written by one of the OKCupid founders. I'm not sure if they have released any datasets from this book.

Answer (score 3):

Pew Research - National Survey of Latinos - "[Family, Fertility, Sexual Behaviors and Attitudes](http://www.pewhispanic.org/2009/12/11/viii-family-fertility-sexual-behaviors-and-attitudes/)"

- [Data download](http://www.pewhispanic.org/2013/07/19/2009-national-survey-of-latinos/) (requires registration)

> Field Dates: 8/5/09 – 9/16/09
>
> Respondents: Nationally-representative sample of 2,012 Latino respondents ages 16 and older
>
> Margin of Error: +/-3.70 percentage points at the 95% confidence level
>
> This survey focused primarily on Latino youth, including questions regarding educational experiences, identity, discrimination, social values, teen sexual activity, parental relationships, crime, and media and technology use.  While Latinos ages 16-25 were oversampled, Latinos ages 26 and older were also interviewed in regards to almost all of the survey topics, as well.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

### The National Longitudinal Study of Adolescent to Adult Health

[Website here](http://www.cpc.unc.edu/projects/addhealth)

This is a tremendously important study, which received a great amount of criticism during its inception and early years. Almost all the data is public and open access.

Still, it was recognized in 2016 with the [Golden Goose Award](http://www.goldengooseaward.org/awardees/add-health), for a scientific project that keeps on giving.

Answer (score 2):

Not open data, but relatively easy to register for:

The British National Surveys of Sexual Attitudes and Lifestyles, or Natsal, are among the largest and most detailed studies of sexual behaviour in the world. Three Natsal surveys have taken place to date: Natsal-1 in 1990-1991 (available from the UK Data Archive under SN 3434), Natsal-2 in 1999-2001 (available under SN 5223) and Natsal-3 in 2010-2012 (available under SN 7799). Further information is available from the Natsal website.

Natsal 3 has a sample size of about 15000 adults living in England, Wales or Scotland:
https://discover.ukdataservice.ac.uk/catalogue/?sn=7799